# Link to get http response works just once in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am having problem to get graphical result for second time either it be for a database query or two or more queries. For first time result is given as desired immediately but thereafter browser just says 'Connecting'. For example after `http://localhost:8000/graph/` gives pie-chart for first time it does not give the pie-chart again when the same link is hit and also any other similar link `http://localhost:8000/graph2/` doesnot work. The latter link would have worked if `http://localhost:8000/graph2/` was hit first after execution of program.

In urls.py links are given as:

```
url(r'^graph/', graph, name = 'ngraph'),
 url(r'^graph2/', graph2, name = 'ngraph2'),
```

Directory structure looks:

[image: project tree]

Detail code is given [HERE](http://goo.gl/7fYiW).

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/grap2/` != `http://localhost:8000/graph2/` .. That was a typo right, cause if not, then I guess that's the reason :)

Comment: Maybe an issue of database, cause I couldn't see any reason Django would freeze there. Can you replace the data from the queries by fake data and check ? And you've no stack trace to show ? :)

Comment: It just says 'Connecting' and hangs around in browser so I couldn't included stack trace. Actually in console also after it works saying "GET /graph/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22302 then "GET /graph/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22302 is not shown anymore when tried. So is it the issue with database?

Comment: Or, can something like server dying or port being closed after 1st access cause such problems?

Comment: I tried with fake database but it didn't helped. I have assured that server had refused connection. Could you please suggest ways around?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. In your urls.py, add a separate pattern object with the prefix set as the views of your app. That would be like `urlpatterns += patterns('welcome.views', url(r'^graph/', ...))`. Rest should be as it is.
2. Dont change urls.py. Instead refer to the complete path in the template starting from your app. In your case that might be `{% url welcome.views.ngraph %}`.

Since you mentioned that GET is not being served at all, it is quite possible that the server cant locate (map) the url to the function.

In an ideal situation, you should `import welcome.views` instead of using `from .. import *` and polluting the urls.py globals. Use the complete path in the patterns object. This way you wont need separate patterns objects for different apps. This would make a lot of sense in a bigger project with more applications. But in any case, this is the standard practice and is encouraged.

Do post your result.